# nest for elasticsearch version 2.0.0.0 partial update on nested objects

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Say, I have some `POCO` like following.

```
public class Graph
{
    public string Id { get; set; } // Indexed by this
    public List<Node> NodeList { get; set; }
}

public class Node
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Edge> EdgeList { get; set; }
}

public class Edge
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public double Cost { get; set; }
}
```

When partially updating my `Graph`
I want to find an existing `Node` in `NodeList` by it's `Id`, and update it's `Name` and `Edge` property. I **do not** want to add new `Node` objects in my `NodeList`. Only want to update existing ones.

Sofar I've tried:

```
public void UpdateGraph(string index, Graph graph)
{
    var docPath = new DocumentPath<Graph>(graph.Id).Index(index);
    try
    {
        var updateResp = client.Update<Graph, Graph>(docPath, searchDescriptor => searchDescriptor
            .Doc(graph)    
            .RetryOnConflict(4)
            .Refresh(true)
        );
    }
}
```

In my current implementation as you can see all I am doing is replacing 
the old `Graph` object. But I want to partially update my `Graph` object. I want to send list of `Node` object as parameter,
Find those in `NodeList` and only update those `Node` Objects.

Maybe some thing like the following,

```
public void UpdateGraph(string index, List<Node> node)
{
    //Code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `NodeList` is a `List<Node>`, a partial update is not possible as the provided value would replace the existing value.

You can however use [optimistic concurrency control](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/optimistic-concurrency-control.html) to

1. get the existing document
2. make the changes in your application
3. index the changed document back into Elasticsearch, using the version number from the get request for optimistic concurrency

Something like the following will work

```
var getResponse = client.Get<Graph>("graph-id");

var graph = getResponse.Source;
var node = graph.NodeList.First(n => n.Id == "node-id");  

// make changes to the node
node.Name = "new name";
node.EdgeList.First().Cost = 9.99;

var indexResponse = client.Index(graph, i => i
    // specify the version from the get request
    .Version(getResponse.Version)
);
```

If the `Graph` has been changed in between the get and the index call, then a 409 response will be returned on the index call.

If you regularly need to update `Node`s and `Edge`s independently of one another, you may decide to model them with [Parent/Child relationships](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html) which would allow you to update without needing to pull back the object graph and index the changes.