# Partially Update Nested Records in ElasticSearch Index

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am using ElasticSearch 2.x with Nest 2 in my project.

I am facing a issue in which i need to update the nested records , but Elasticsearch doesn't do that, instead it deletes the records and re-index them.

So because of this scenario, i need to always send all the nested records along with the updated one to update the nested records.

So has anyone of you has a solution of this? Can i only update the record without re-indexing all records?

Thanks for your help in advance..!!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39722500/nest-for-elasticsearch-version-2-0-0-0-partial-update-on-nested-objects

Comment: Thanks @RussCam , it worked like magic... Was stucked on this for quiet a while, you saved a hell of time for me.. Thanks a lot again.. :)

Comment: Happy to help. Feel free to upvote that answer :)

Comment: Also consider the quite new `UpdateByQuery` - feature of ES which often helps to save a lot of code: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html

Comment: @core `UpdateByQuery` is still bound by the same constraints of updating nested documents as the Update API; it just allows you to update many documents with one call

Answer (score 1):

**Try this,**
It works for me

```
POST /yourindex/type/_id/_update
{
    "script" : {
        "inline" :  "if (ctx._source.yourarray == null || ctx._source.yourarray.size() == 0){ ctx._source.yourarray = params.uuuser}  else {ctx._source.yourarray.add(params.newarray[0]) } ", 
        "params" : {
            "newarray" :[ 
               {"c1":"dfgfgsdf",
                 "c2":"can2",
                 "ce":" can2@can.co",
                 "cp":475522778,
                 "d1":[
                       {
                         "e1":"fffff",
                         "ffff":[{"g1":"hhhhh"},{"g2":"iiiiii"}]
                       }
                   ] 
               }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```